# Security of Blind Signature Schemes in the Concurrent Setting

Tags: blind-signature

I am quite confused about the security definition of blind signature schemes in the concurrent setting. I have found a paper as follows showing that most of the previous blind signature schemes cannot satisfy unforgeability property if they are deployed in the concurrent setting.

Benhamouda, Fabrice, et al. "On the (in) security of ROS." Annual International Conference on the Theory and Applications of Cryptographic Techniques. Springer, Cham, 2021.

Does this mean that most of the previous blind signature schemes do not allow multiple users to request blind signatures from a signer at the same time?

In other words, if multiple users want to request blind signatures and send their requests to a signer, the signer cannot handle them concurrently. It starts to sign one request of one user and pauses the other requests, and after the signing session is finished, it signs the next request of another user.